# Does electric field break inversion symmetry while magnetic field break time reversal symmetry?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter

From many papers I've read in condensed matter physics, it seems "breaking time reversal symmetry" is often equivalent to "applying an external B field", while "breaking inversion symmetry" can be done (but not limited to) by "applying an electric field". Is this true in general?

A side question: if a perturbation breaks the inversion symmetry of the original Hamiltonian, does that imply it mixes states of opposite parity? Similarly, if a perturbation breaks time-reversal symmetry, does that mixes time-reversal pairs?
Looking forward to any counter-examples. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the rigorous way to think about symmetry is if the equation of motion or Hamiltonian is invariant under a certain symmetry operation. In the case of time reversal symmetry, $t\rightarrow -t$.

One quick way to see that a magnetic field breaks time-reversal symmetry is to consider the elementary example of a charged particle moving in circular motion driven by a field. If we apply time-reversal symmetry, the particle is now moving in the opposite direction and therefore effectively, $B\rightarrow -B$. Or that applying a magnetic field chooses a certain path direction, breaking the time-reversal symmetry. This is analogous to the condensed matter system when we discuss spins.

Similarly, inversion symmetry maps $\vec{x}\rightarrow-\vec{x}$. Let us think about the simplest example of the E field of a charged particle at the origin. Clearly, the E field does not break any inversion symmetry. But if you consider a uniform E field along some direction, then physics is different after applying inversion symmetry.

I'm not sure what you mean by mixing the pairs. I think you are thinking about something like Kramer's theorem. In which case, the breaking of said symmetry actually lifts the degeneracy.